# Cannot resolve GoogleApiClient after updating to Google Play Services 8.3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-play-services

I am working on a project that depends on Google Play Services 8.1.0, and have tried to update to 8.3.0 as detailed here: [Setting Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

After syncing my gradle scripts and trying to build, I can no longer resolve anything that comes from Google Play Services. It's a simple number increment in my build script:

```
dependencies {
    //google play services components
    def playServicesVersion = '8.3.0'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:${playServicesVersion}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${playServicesVersion}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:${playServicesVersion}"
    ...
```

When the number for *playServicesVersion* is set to "8.1.0" my project builds fine. When switched to "8.3.0" - nothing from Google Play Services are resolved, i.e. all of these and more cannot be found:

```
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.Credential;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.CredentialRequest;
```

and so on. I feel like I must be overlooking something simple.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that we are extending some classes that has changed some of their abstract method signatures and my project would not compile. I was incorrectly focusing on the inability to resolve imports instead, when I should have been paying attention compilation messages rather than the Gradle console. After changing the overridden method signatures compilation was successful. I doubt that anyone else would encounter this blunder, please forgive my newbie mistake...

Answer (score 0):

Possibly 8.1.0 is already available in your gradle cache.

Changing to 8.3.0 requires a download and I noted another question earlier which stated that the Google download site was giving a 404 error.

[Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list.xml 404 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33934077/failed-to-fetch-url-http-dl-ssl-google-com-android-repository-addons-list-xml)