# Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list.xml 404 not found

Tags: java, android, adt

I am trying to update lastest android SDK manager on lastest JDK 1.8. Updating gives me info about failed xml fetch, also I can't open it in the browser:

[image]

Any attempts to install any updates fail this way:

[image]

I am on windows7 64bit, no proxy, no firewall, running manager as admin.

Tried:

- (un)checking https checkbox
- removing java64, reinstalled jdk
- setting proxy
- passing -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true arg to java.exe
- setting ANDROID_SDK_HOME

but nothing helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found a solution.

1. get this one: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml (it doesn't give 404)
2. find a name of .zip file inside matching your platform (for me it was tools_r22.6.2-windows.zip)
3. find contents in C:/Program Files/Android/, matching contents of archive. Replace files from folder with content from archive.

These steps are enough to make Android SDK functional.

PS: as for 27.11.2015 this can be reproduced on clean VirtualBox with Windows 7: install jdk 1.8, android SDK and you will run into this trouble.